# Does reassigning the reference to a javascript array to another empty array free memory used by the original array?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

So let's say you have an array:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and then you reassign the referrence to that array to a new empty array:

```
array = [];
```

Is that original array removed from memory now that there are no more references to it?

Comment: No. But if there is no reference held to that array it becomes 'qualified' for garbage collection

Answer (score 0):

Probably not immediately (as part of the reassignment), but so long as the reference count to it has dropped to `0` (there is no other variable pointing to *that* array), it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no (if the var names are different [seeing that you changed the question]), and yes as in the new example added in your question.  In the case the var names are different you can free up some memory if need be by making the original array null, however they will both take space.  In array 2 you are actually making a new array with the contents of the first array.  Objects (assoc arrays in js) are a different story, however following the reference rules mentioned above.

If you use the same var name in the same scope, then yes. The second call will free up the memory from the first scenario